# Eliminate saturated areas in Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I was reading a paper about image fusion image processing in which they mentioned that eliminating saturated areas. It's like this:

> the saturated pixels of the long-exposed image are not included in the estimation.

and

> Eliminate saturated areas by re-setting the joint histogram entries that are closer than a threshold from the maximum value 255 (In our work we used a threshold of 10)

There are some things I don't understand here, like "saturated pixels", "saturated areas", "re-setting", and "closer than a threshold from the maximum value". How can I determine them, and hơ can I do this with OpenCV in Python?
Thank you in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is the paper link:
[Image enhancement method via blur and noisy image fusion](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224114693_Image_enhancement_method_via_blur_and_noisy_image_fusion)

Comment: Convert to HSV colorspace and threshold on S (saturation) channel to find the regions of high saturation.

Comment: can you explain the 2nd idea: Eliminate saturated areas by re-setting the joint histogram entries that are closer than a threshold from the maximum value 255 (In our work we used a threshold of 10)

Comment: Do you have the correct link? I do not see those statements in it.

Comment: @fmw42 "saturation" here means sensor clipping, not color saturation.

Comment: @fmw42 i had changed a little, but u can find those statements in sections 2, step 3

Comment: My best guess is that they are cropping the 2D histogram (comparagram) at the two extremes. But that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

A camera sensor is said to be saturated when in some portion of the image area the measured intensities are not proportional to the amount of light reaching the sensor. Think of a pixel site as a "smart" bucket that counts photons falling inside it within a certain exposure time. The counter can only grow so much (say, up to 255, for 8-bit counters) so, if too many photons arrive within the exposure time, it will hit 255 and stay pegged there no matter how much light arrives thereafter. The pixel will look white. In some kinds of sensors (e.g. CCD's) things can get worse: the saturated pixels will also "spill" counts onto neighboring un-saturated ones, causing "streaks" of white in the image going even far away from the  image of the bright object in the scene that is causing the saturation - for example, the sun.

Saturation can adversely affect many image processing algorithms that depend on image intensities being in a smooth, roughly linear, relationship with scene light radiance, and so care must be taken to identify and treat in special way saturated areas in an image, if any are present.

To detect saturated areas in an image one should not fixate on the "255" value (for 8bpp): a pixel can be white in absence of saturation. Rather one should pay attention to more general properties:

- Saturation typically occurs in regions ("patches) of the image, not isolated pixels, if the sensor has reasonably high resolution.
- Saturation is defined by lack of linear relationship between scene and image intensity, not by the value at the top of the pixel range: a region of an 8bpp sensor may be saturated at a level of 250, for example, it the sensor saturates at that value. This is why the authors of the paper you mention use a threshold of 10 levels below the maximum.

Comment: Your answer is so informative, sir. So what I should do is change all pixel values from 255 to 245?

Comment: Sir, can you reply me?